# Excel formula for returning a specific weekday of a collection based on the cell referenced

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to use a formula to return the first day of a week for a date. I would also like Saturday to be considered as the 'first day' of a week in this formula.

For example, B2 is 03/03/2014. B3 is 04/03/2014. B4 is 05/03/2014.

What formula can I use in A2:A4 that will return a value of 01/03/2014? (01/03/2014 being Saturday).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the **weekday** function gives you the day of the week with the default being Sunday=1 to Saturday=7.

Using this a formula in A2 could be

> =if(weekday(B2)=7,B2,B2-weekday(B2))

Answer (score 1):

gtwebb's answer is nice, but it only works if your starting date is always Saturday. If you attempt any other weekday value, the formula will not auto-populate correctly.

I found that using this works nicely for all commencing days in a week:

=IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=2, B2, A1)

This will look at the weekday directly above, and will only work if your spreadsheet is sorted oldest to newest, and if you definitely have at least one entry for each starting day in a week, but you can easily copy and paste over as a value for any large datasets.

Of course I would not have thought of this had I not used gtwebb's answer; so thank you!!